# Checking for existence of Boost::boost target fails

Tags: boost, cmake

Some of my `CMakeLists.txt` files contain checks whether an imported target exists. This is to make sure the build process also runs with `CMake` versions less than 3.8, as the `Boost::boost` target has been added to the `FindBoost.cmake` module in this version.

```
if (NOT TARGET Boost::boost)
  list(APPEND INCLUDE_DIRS_TO_ADD "${Boost_INLUDE_DIRS}")
else()
  list(APPEND TARGET_DEPENDENCIES_TO_ADD Boost::boost)
endif()
```

I tested it on `Ubuntu 19.04` and `macOS 10.14` with success.

But now I got complains from a `macOS` and `linux` user that is using `CMake 3.14.3` and `boost-cpp 1.68` that the dependencies are not correctly set on his side with the error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Boost::boost;OpenGL::GL;OpenGL::GLU;Threads::Threads;EXPAT::EXPAT;OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY
```

Is this the right way to handle this, or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It seems that CMake treats the whole "Boost::boost;OpenGL::GL;OpenGL::GLU;Threads::Threads;EXPAT::EXPAT;OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY" as a **single-value** argument. Looks like you enclose some *multi-value* variable into double quotes, like you do in `"${Boost_INLUDE_DIRS}"` (plural suffix `DIRS` implies that there could be more than one directory in this variable, so enclosing it into double quotes is not correct).

Comment: Thank you so much @Tsyvarev. That solved my issue. If you make that an answer I'll gladly accept it.